how do i customize ubuntu 22.04 iso and rebuild it?
I am going to keep it simple. i want to create an iso which uses user-data file from a web server url while booting . for that i know i have to edit the menuentry in grub.cfg.
I am using following commands from the start:

sudo apt update
sudo apt install squashfs-tools genisoimage xorriso cloud-image-utils
wget https://releases.ubuntu.com/jammy/ubuntu-22.04.4-live-server-amd64.iso
mkdir -p ~/custom_iso/iso
mkdir ~/custom_iso/mount
sudo mount -o loop ubuntu-22.04.4-live-server-amd64.iso ~/custom_iso/mount
rsync -a ~/custom_iso/mount/ ~/custom_iso/iso/
sudo umount ~/custom_iso/mount

After these step i am using following command to rebuild the iso.
mkisofs -r -V "CUSTOM_UBUNTU" 
-e EFI/boot/bootx64.efi -no-emul-boot 
-o ../custom-ubuntu.iso ~/custom_iso/iso/
After deploying the created ISO it says boot failed.
dont really know why is it happening.

This question is similar to: How to Duplicate a Ubuntu System for Distribution?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

DON'T. What you will be doing is only valid for a short time and VERY timeconsuming. It is only intesting in learning how the installer works. Far far easier method:  Install it normally. Then create a script to do what you want to do post-install, and use that for future install.

but i want to try and see if the user data file really works and installs what is mentioned in it while booting. so far its a failure. i cant seem to understand how to rebuild the iso. plus its a requirement for me to customize the iso

There are a lot of steps involved with unpacking and repacking a custom ISO. You can try using Cubic. Otherwise, you may be able to find the needed steps at these links: Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop Autoinstall and Ubuntu Autoinstall Generator

"plus its a requirement for me to customize the iso" Is this some kind of school assignment?

for cubic i would need a desktop version of ubuntu. Is there any way that i could do this with ubuntu server. i have tried a lot of options. but the iso that i build isn't booting.
